# How can I add subscript in graph titles? I tried a code and it ran well for the first time however, its giving me an error. Any help is appreciated!

Tags: data-visualization, ggplot2

I tried this code and it ran well for the first time however, its giving me an error. Any help is appreciated!

```
q<-ggplot(data=R_PRS_Graph1, 
(x=Date, y=Ammonium, group=Treatment,shape=Treatment, 
color=Treatment)) + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Ammonium-SE,
ymax=Ammonium+SE), width=.1)+geom_line(size=1.0) 
+geom_point(size=2) + 
labs(title = (expression(paste(Cumulative~NH[4]^{+}-N Release))))
```

Comment: If you want to distinguish whether the next letter is subscript or not , you need to use star ( * ). And, anything that is not a number ( alphabets or symbols etc) should be put in quotation marks.  In your example, we can try to use this code: title=(expression('Cumulative NH'[4]^' +' * '- N Release'))

Comment: Thanks J-H Yoon for your help but it didn't work!

Comment: The code on the label of the corresponding title works well. Do you try to run this another example code?: ggplot(diamonds) + geom_point(aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) + geom_smooth(aes(x=carat, y=price))+labs(title=(expression('Cumulative NH'[4]^' +' * '- N Release')))